# Class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer could not be found

Tags: json, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, jsonserializer

I'm new to ***Confluent Cloud*** and deploying it using free trial of Confluent Kafka cluster.
I am trying to ***produce/consume the JSON messages from Kafka Topic using authenticated Schema Registry*** which can map Schema.
I am referring to the official documentation https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/serdes-json.html
but the **JSON serializers mentioned is not working.**
I am getting below error in my SCALA code:

```
Invalid value io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer for configuration value.serializer: Class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer could not be found.
```

Could you please let us know if this has been deprecated or not valid anymore?
Can someone please advise here?

This is my exact build.sbt :

```
name := "JsonProducer"  
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.12.5"
resolvers += "confluent" at "https://packages.confluent.io/maven/" // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.confluent/kafka-json-schema-serializer 
libraryDependencies += "io.confluent" % "kafka-json-schema-serializer" % "6.2.0"
```

Comment: have u found any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Solved this by adding these dependencies in build.sbt:

```
resolvers += "jitpack" at "https://jitpack.io"
libraryDependencies += "org.everit.json" % "org.everit.json.schema" % "1.5.1"
libraryDependencies += "io.confluent" % "kafka-json-schema-serializer" % "6.2.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this dependency

```
"io.confluent" % "kafka-json-schema-serializer" % "6.2.0"
```

Comment: I have tried adding this dependency

**libraryDependencies += “io.confluent” % “kafka-json-schema-serializer” % "6.2.0"**

in my build.sbt file but it doesn’t get successful.

`Extracting structure failed, reason: not ok build status: Error (BuildMessages(Vector(),Vector(BuildFailure(sbt task failed, see log for details)),Vector(),Vector(),Error))
sbt task failed, see log for details`

`scalaVersion := “2.12.5”
sbt.version = 1.5.2`

Any suggestions please?

Comment: You also need to add the Confluent Maven repo to your project

Comment: I am using `resolvers += "confluent" at "https://packages.confluent.io/maven/"`... Do I need to add something else? @OneCricketeer

Comment: @AditiSinha Seems okay to me, but I've not used SBT in years. If you use IntelliJ, you can open the "External Libraries" part of the project tab to see if that dependency is downloaded, then expand it to find the class you want

Comment: The problem is in adding this  **libraryDependencies += “io.confluent” % “kafka-json-schema-serializer” % "6.2.0"**; All my other confluent dependencies are getting downloaded and is added to external dependencies but while building this dependency, I get error stating : build failed!! Seems like this dependency also needs some other libraries?? Not sure though. Any suggestions?