# JSON and Schema Registry

Tags: json, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to produce **JSON records from my Scala Producer code to  Kafka topic**. It is successfully generated, however I am **not able to register the schema and do schema evolution compatibility checks**.

I am not able to find any proper code/doc references. How do I register my JSON schema and consume by connecting to schema registry client and check for the compatibilities.

Any suggestions please? (more about what am trying [Class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68576395/class-io-confluent-kafka-serializers-json-kafkajsonschemaserializer-could-not-be))

Answer (score 0):

Compatibilities are checked server-side automatically upon producing, which in-turn registers the schemas, by default.

You provide `schema.registry.url` to the Producer and Consumer properties when using the clients and the `JSONSchema(De)Serializer` classes

Comment: @OneCricketeer- Using the kafka-json-schema-serializer I am now able to connect to schema registry. But the values are not coming in correctly.More about what am trying to do https://stackoverflow.com/q/68621280/16554106. Any  suggestions?