# JSONSchema values not sent when using Scala Case class

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry, jsonserializer

I have a Scala Kafka Producer code where I am using a case class to initialize values and trying to send it using the Producer.

```
case class User(id: Int,name: String,contact: Int, dept: String)
```

Using this class to initialize values in my code:

```
 val rec: User = User(101,"abc",999,"ab1")
```

Producer sending json records using serializer:

```
> key->"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"
> value->"io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer"
```

--CODE that Iam trying:

```
 val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, User](props)
    val callback = new Callback {
      override def onCompletion(metadata: RecordMetadata, exception: Exception): Unit = {
        Option(exception) match {
          case Some(err) => println(s"Failed to produce: $err")
          case None => println(s"Produced record at $metadata")
        }
      }
    }
             val usr: User = User(101,"abc",999,"ab1")//case class User(id: Int,name: String,contact: Int, dept: String)

        val record = new ProducerRecord[String,User](topicName, "key", usr)
      try {
                   producer.send(record,callback).get()
      }
      catch {
        case e: Throwable =>
          println(e.getMessage)
      }
    producer.flush()
    producer.close()
```

But the values are coming as **{}** in my kafka topic.
If I try to print the record part, I see this getting sent:

> key=key, value=User(101,abc,999,ab1)

Also, in the confluent schema registry the schema is coming as:

> ```
> {
>   "additionalProperties": false,
>   "properties": {},
>   "title": "User",
>   "type": "object"
> }
> ```

Not sure why it is not correctly sending the records. Any suggestions?

> I want to send records as: key=key,
> value={"id":101,"name":"abc","contact":999,"dept":"ab1"}

and my schema registry should register all these columns in its schema as:

```
{
       "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {"id": { "type": "integer"},.....},
       "title": "User",
       "type": "object"
   }
```

Comment: I don't think this is a Kafka issue. It's case-class & Jackson that causes the fields to be serialized or not. If you checkout the source-code of the registry, you can set a breakpoint here - https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/json-schema-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/json/AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaSerializer.java#L108

Comment: @OneCricketeer- I think the values are getting serialized but the problem seems to be in passing the object of the Case Class that I have created. Records are getting sent as key=key, **value=User(101,abc,999,ab1)** but I guess if we send it like key=key, value=101,abc,999,ab1 I will get the fields in here`{        "additionalProperties": false,       "properties": {"id": { "type": "integer"},.....},        "title": "User",        "type": "object"    }` ... **Added code for reference**

Comment: You're printing the Scala toString representation, not the JSON serialized record. Like I said, that's not a Kafka issue, but rather that the Schema Registry serializers dont know how to handle Scala-to-Java class conversions. If you literally want to send as `value={"id":101,"name":"abc","contact":999,"dept":"ab1"}`, then you should not be using the JSON **schema** serializer or the registry

Comment: @OneCricketeer- oh okay!! Do you have any code references or what serializer would you suggest?

Comment: `org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter` is built-in to Kafka, but doesn't integrate with the Registry, so it wouldn't generate the output you've shown in the question

Comment: I just found that there's this https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala, which claims to support case class serialization, but it is not used by the Confluent libraries, and I'm not sure what adding it to your own classpath will do since you'd still need to configure the internal serializer's ObjectMapper instance, which isn't public